# jQuery Adding Current Date to Text Field

Tags: jquery

After a bit of advice. I am using the following code to add the current date to a textbox on a user form. 99% of the time it works perfectly, displaying the date in dd/mm/yyyy (UK Format). But occasionally when a user completes the form and their browser is set to (US Format) the date flips in the text box. mm/dd/yyyy

Can anyone recommend how I can force this to always submit in dd/mm/yyyy ?

```
function myFunction() {
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleDateString();
document.getElementById("FIELD_11575").defaultValue = n;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the locale to use:

```
var n = d.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
```

MDN: [Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Answer (score 0):

`toLocaleDateString()` accepts locale.
Specify the format using  `toLocaleDateString("en-US")` or `toLocaleDateString("en-GB")` as you need.